# Switching tab resets databound selection

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview

I've been working on a C# project which uses a `TabControl`.  I have a `DataTable` which is bound, using the same `DataView` to two different entities, a `ListBox` in one tab, and a `DataGridView` in another.

I've started saving the user's selection for those controls between launches.  At launch, both the `ListBox` and the `DataGridView` are set to the correct values.  When the tab switch occurs, if I haven't changed the selected item in the `ListBox`, the selected row on the `DataGridView` gets set to `null`, and then the `SelectedIndexChanged` callback for the `ListBox` gets called, believing that the first item in the list was selected.  If, however, I force the tab with the `DataGridView` to be displayed at launch, the issue does not occur.

Neither control nor the tabs have any callbacks when displayed or entered.  I'm running out of ideas here.

Sample Code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Updates several on-screen controls based on the currently selected item.
/// </summary>
private void updateDisplay()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Selection (ListBox): " + myListBox.SelectedIndex);
    Console.WriteLine("Selection (DataGridView): " + ((myDataGridView.SelectedRows.Count > 0) ? (""+myDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Index) : ("null"));

    // Update the various labels and textboxes.
}

/// <summary>
/// Callback when the selected index of myListBox changes.
/// </summary>
private void myListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    updateDisplay();
}

/// <summary>
/// Callback when the selected row of myDataGridView changes.
/// </summary>
private void myDataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    updateDisplay();
}
```

Results:
// On launch
Selection (ListBox): 1
Selection (DataGridView): 1

// After tab change
Selection (ListBox): 0
Selection (DataGridView): null

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/91743/bindingsource-clears-non-visible-fields-in-tabcontrol-set-by-program) helps:

> DataBinding doesn't occur on Controls
>   until the Controls are created. A
>   TabPage creates child controls only
>   after the TabPage has been made
>   visible. To get DataBinding to occur,
>   you'll need to force the child
>   controls on the TabPage to be created
>   and one way you can do that is by
>   showing/hiding the TabPage (as you
>   have discovered).

Comment: That makes sense.  Unfortunately simply calling Show() then Hide() on that TabPage didn't create the Controls like I'd hoped.  For now, I'm just forcing the focus to be on that TabPage until I can figure out a better solution.