# Why combobox refresh doesn't work?

Tags: .net, winforms, combobox, tabcontrol, datarelation

I have a complex problem, could you please help me.

The problem:

I have a form with a `TabControl`. There are two `TabPages` in the first is a `dataGridView` and in the second are multiple `comboboxes`.

`DataGridView` is filled with data from `Table1`, on the other tab the first `combobox` datasource is set to `TableCB1`, the second `combobox` to `TableCB2` etc.

Between `TableCB1, TableCB2` ... are `DataRelations` like (`TableCB1.ID->TableCB2.ParentID`). I'm using databindings to bind current columns from table to controls.

**When I open the form, first tabPage (`dataGridView`) is filled and works ok, but if I select the second TabPage (with `comboboxes`) then the `combobox` selected items are not correct selected!!!** Only the first `combobox` is set correctly but all other have selected the first item in datasource until I change the bindingsource position or make `dataset.rejectchanges()`.

But if make TabPage two to be shown on form load, then the combobox items are selected correctly!

I know it's a very specific problem but, hope somebody could help me to solve this problem.

I'm doing it on .NET3.5 and winforms.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reply in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187057/switching-tab-resets-databound-selection/2187418#2187418) thread might be what you need:

> DataBinding doesn't occur on Controls until the Controls are created. A TabPage creates child controls only after the TabPage has been made visible. To get DataBinding to occur, you'll need to force the child controls on the TabPage to be created and one way you can do that is by showing/hiding the TabPage (as you have discovered).